# Is this the idiomatic way to get the wanted variant out of an enum without causing nesting?

Tags: rust, destructuring

I have this working code:

```
/* Ignore IPv6. */
let via = if let IpAddr::V4(via) = addr.ip() {
    via
} else {
    warn!("(unsupported) ipv6 packet from ${addr}");
    continue // abandon this packet and try the next packet
};

// ...process this packet with "via: Ipv4Addr" in scope...
```

Is there an idiomatic way to get the wanted variant out of an enum, without `via` being mentioned three times?

Or is this how I should ignore unwanted variants in Rust?

Comment: The question linked as duplicate is how to get the value (at all). This question is about avoiding nesting and/or repetition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `let`-`else`, since the `else` branch is diverging (`continue`):

```rust
/* Ignore IPv6. */
let IpAddr::V4(via) = addr.ip() else {
    warn!("(unsupported) ipv6 packet from ${addr}");
    continue // abandon this packet and try the next packet
};

// ...process this packet with "via: Ipv4Addr" in scope...
```